# Why do std::hex and void* on an integer result in the same value

Tags: c++

For example in C++:

```
    int number = 10;
    cout << std::hex << number << endl;
    cout << (void *)(int)number << endl;
```

Why do the two outputs have the same hex value?

What does the `(void *)(int)number` really mean here?

Comment: The `(int)` cast is redundant. The second line could be `cout << (void*)number << endl;`

Answer (score 5):

This is, I believe, *implementation defined* behavior.

As a practical matter:

- Formatted output of pointers tends to give the address they point to.
- At the level of machine code, pointers tend to be stored as a 32-bit or 64-bit integer representing a memory address.
- The cast tends to be implemented by simply reinterpreting the machine language integer as representing a pointer.